# HP ILO and Vmware ESXi, how to assign HP ILO to specific virtual guest machine?

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp-proliant, rhcs

I m using RHCS, and one of the important part is to have fencing working for my environment. Normally using a physical server, i can simply used the ILO as my fence device. However as guest machine inside esxi, sending reboot instruction via ILO fencing, will actually reboot the host/physical machine.

Is there anyway in vsphere/esxi management part that i can assign ILO to a specific vm guest machine, so that fencing will only affected a single vm guest.

I m using the latest vmware vsphere hypervisor.

or is there any other choice of fencing and reliable ?

Comment: The iLO will not be aware of the guests, it sounds to me like you need to talk to the APIs of the Hypervisor.

Comment: thanks spacemanSpiff, i think the only way is by developing my own fence agent using vi toolkit or via hypervisor soap interface.

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick google for "RHCS vsphere fence agent" and found this [link](http://www.wcborstel.com/article/creating-virtual-red-hat-cluster-vmware-vsphere.html), which references a third-part script that sounds like it does what you want.

I have no idea if it'll help, I just mashed some keys at google because your problem sounded interesting :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `fence_vmware_soap` which is available in RHCS or CentOS 6.2 or later.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this. Why don't you explain better what you're actually trying to achieve and we may be able to help you.

Comment: I don't know why this got downvoted, it can't be done, that's the answer. I did try offer to help the user if they came back to me with extra details.